# What's the opposite of spin collapse? Superposition as a verb?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, quantum-spin, superposition

With regard to photon spin, I'm trying to figure out what the word is for being "more random" as opposed to collapsing and being "more determined"

If I were to say "the spin collapsed", how would I say the opposite? The spin superpositioned??

Comment: Perhaps a state of quantum coherence is appropriate? Whatever the opposite of decoherence is. To cohere?

Comment: I would use "the spins are superposed" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superpose